# Finding the min of a range of cells that correspond to specific dates

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, cell

I have a very lengthy list of cells that contain dates and corresponding speeds.
There are multiple speeds for every day because it is hourly data. I need to find a way to find the maximum speed of every day and paste it to another column R.

Something like "if date = 01/01/2000 then cells (i,"R") = minimum speed for that day and so on for every date in my sheet.

this is for i = 2 to 150000 
(i being the number of rows of data)

sample of the how the sheet looks

Spd     ----    Date

12      -----    01/01/2000

18------          01/01/2000

11     ------ 01/01/2000

13  -----   01/02/2000

31  -----   01/02/2000

44  -----   01/02/2000

Comment: in excel 2016 you can just use a =MINIF() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, in another cell enter the *Array Formula*:

```
=MIN(IF(B1:B24=DATEVALUE("9/17/2016"),A1:A24))
```

To get the minimum speed for 9/17/2016:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Thank You, this Array function is very useful